# Remove path from result of find -name Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm currently trying to code a script that looks through a given directory for a selection of words contained in a txt file.
The code is quite simple for the moment :

```
dir=$1
shift
find $dir -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' | xargs grep -o -f "$@" | sort -u
```

We can run it by :

```
sh search.sh directory filename
```

The result looks like that :

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-25/scripts/sortextable.h:void
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-25/scripts/unifdef.c:continue
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-25/scripts/unifdef.c:default
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-25/scripts/unifdef.c:do
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-25/scripts/unifdef.c:for
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-25/scripts/unifdef.c:if
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-25/scripts/unifdef.c:of
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-25/scripts/unifdef.c:size
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-25/scripts/unifdef.c:static
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-25/scripts/unifdef.c:unsigned
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-25/scripts/unifdef.c:void
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-25/scripts/unifdef.c:while
```

Now as you can see, for each word found in the file, the absolute path is written even if the previous one was in the same file.

Now what I want to do is to write something like : 
*path* contains these words : *list of words* (static if unsigned)

I'm trying to do that in the shortest possible time using pipes if it's possible.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Just do `.. | sort -u | awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{unique[$1]=(unique[$1]" "$2)}END{for (i in unique) printf "%s contains %s\n",i,unique[i]}' 
`